# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase': Error: Uh oh

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic5

I am trying to install the cordova-plugin-firebase in my ionic app but it's not working
I have cordova-android version 9.1.0
When I try to install the plugin it says

Installing "cordova-plugin-firebase" for android
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase': Error: Uh oh!
EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'platforms\android\app\src\main'

Please help me on this because I have tried almost more than 2 days on that but unable to find any solution for that

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`cordova-plugin-firebase` is not maintained anymore, you need to use the following plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
```

Check here for more info:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-x 
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex

Comment: There are a lot of errors in the installation of firebasex plugin in ionic 5. Have you tried to install that?

Comment: yes couple of month ago.. you need to be a bit familiar with gradle to solve the errors. What errors are you getting? Maybe open an issue on github then